# Using a PostBack on a LinkButton in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, postback

I have an .ascx control in my searchresults.aspx page:

```
 <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1"
       Text="Click Me" 
       Font-Names="Verdana" 
       Font-Size="14pt" PostBackUrl="~/searchresults.aspx?type=topics"  
       runat="server"/>
```

But when I click on it, it does the postback but the type=topics doesn't appear to be sent. Any suggestions?

Comment: i think i just read that it uses Request.Form instead of QueryString, lemme check

Comment: nope somehow still not working

Comment: Why not use Button? Why it must be LinkButton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out [HyperLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to navigate to *an other* page:

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/searchresults.aspx?type=topics" />
```

From MSDN:

> *HyperLink*
>   A control that displays a link to another Web page.

On [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class page:

> If you want to link to another Web page when the control is clicked, 
>   consider using the HyperLink control.

**EDIT: Answer to comments**

- Remove `PostBackUrl` from `LinkButton`
- Add `<asp:LinkButton OnClick="OnTopicsTypesEnabled" ... />`
- In code behind (`searchresults.aspx.cs`)

```
 protected void OnTopicsTypesEnabled(object sender, EventArgs args)
 {
    // handle this particular case
 }
```

Comment: hyperlinks would be fine if they had postback, i don't want a full page request

Comment: @chris : What you mean a full page request?

Comment: i meant refresh, postback only does a partial refresh on the page..I don't want to completely link to another page

Comment: @chris : could you give me a link to description regarding partial refresh whilst postback? really interesting

Comment: Check out documentation, LinkButton.PostBackUrl does ***Post Back* either to itself or an other page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.postbackurl.aspx

Comment: yeah but how do i pass the value of the link to the page_load (code-behing)?

Comment: i want to stay on the page i'm on, and update the searchresults

Comment: do i have to put an onclick or onload in the link button?

Comment: OnClick (LinkButton.Click event, OnClick EventHandler)

Comment: Coudl you describe more how you filtering search results whilst button click? SO you have a set of buttons and each of them passing different filter value? It is not clear, looks like there is could be more efficient solution

Comment: i have a set of links by topics on the left side of my page and search results on the right. I also have a search by keywords on the left side too. If you click a search by topic it will update search reusults by topic OR if you search via keywords the search results are updated by keywords

Comment: how do you pass linkButton OnClick in my ascx file to the searchresults.aspx.cs file?

Comment: @chris let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2554/discussion-between-sllev-and-chris)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your code will perform an POST, whereas you need a GET to transfer your variables through QueryString.

Comment: If it does a post it won't grab the querystring as its not a GET, how do i pass data with the linkbutton then?

Comment: Depending on how your application is structured, you could just change the method to GET on the form. Your other option is to add a click event for the LinkButton, and redirect to the URL.